# Java BubbleSort

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I am facing a problem where I need to sort a String array in alphabetical order. I am able to sort one array, but the problem starts when there are 2 more arrays, that correspond to the first array. Each value in each array should be in the same place, to make information not messed up. After sorting `array1`, it is in alphabetical order, but i don't have any idea how to make values from `array2` and `array3` change the positions the same like in `array1` after sorting is finished.

My code so far is:

```
public  void sort() 
{

    boolean finish = false;

    while(finish == false){

        finish = true;

        for(int i=0;i<Country.length-1;i++)

        {
            int num = 0;
            if(Country[i] != null && Country[i + 1] != null)
            {
                String name1=Country[i]; String name2=Country[i+1];
                num=name1.compareTo(name2);
            }
            else if(Country[i] == null && Country[i + 1] == null){
                num = 0;
            }
            else if(Country[i] == null){
                num = 1;
            }
            else {
                num = -1;
            }
            if(num>0)
            {
                String temp=Country[i];

                Country[i]=Country[i+1];
                Country[i+1]=temp;
                finish=false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Country array values, for example, are {z,a}; And City Values are {2,1} After Sorting Country Array I want City Array to swap Values in the same positions as it swapped in Country Array

Comment: Are you allowed to make custom, comparable object classes to hold all the data? That way, you only need to sort one array instead of multiple.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake is that I  started to create GUI based on 3 array thing and now if I want to change it, I need to change whole program and design as well. That's why I'm trying to get at least some kind of hint what to do, to save my time.

Comment: First question: Do you have to manually implement Bubble Sort? There are built-in Java sorting methods that perform much better. Anyways, what is your data? You have a `City`, a `Country`, and something else that represents a place? So you make a `Place[]` (a custom class) and you sort all the `Place` objects based on their `Country` string value. That way, all the data is "in the correct order"

Comment: It is not mandatory to manually implement Bubble Sort. I just want to understand how it works exactly that's why I want to implement it manually, at the  first time when I use it. My Arrays are City, Country and Population. When All the County's are in alphabetical order, I want city and population to stay in the same place , so after showing them in textArea in one row will be UK, London and whatever population it is. At the moment, cities and population numbers are getting messed up after Sorting Country Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the most recommended way is to re-design your program, and arrange all the related items in a single class. This is what objects are for, after all. Then you can make the object `Comparable`, give it a `compareTo` method, and sort it.

But if you are really unable to do that, what you should do is, whenever you exchange any two items in your sort array, make sure you exchange the corresponding items in the other arrays.

So, if you have arrays `country`, `capital` and `headOfState`, you will have to write something like:

```
  String temp=country[i];

  country[i]=country[i+1];
  country[i+1]=temp;

  temp=capital[i];
  capital[i]=capital[i+1];
  capital[i+1]=temp;

  temp=headOfState[i];
  headOfState[i]=headOfState[i+1];
  headOfState[i+1]=temp;
```

This way, whenever you move anything in your main array, you'll also be moving the respective item in the other arrays, so they will stay together.

But again, it's much more preferred if you re-designed your program.

Also note the Java language conventions - variable names should not start with a capital letter, only type names should.

Comment: Agree with redesign advice. OP really should create a new object holding related data.

Comment: Thank You So Much! This Works For me. I Agree with you and I will redesign it as soon as I will finish this version, just to be able to compare pros and cons from doing in each way.  Anyway, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the array to be swaped based on the compare you did in the country array. You can just swap more than one array after one compare.

```
If(array1[i] > array1[i+1]){
    Swap(array1[i],array1[i+1)
    Swap(array2[i],array2[i+1])
}
```

By using a swap function, you can make it more simpler to do swaping in much more array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap elements in `Country` and `City` arrays simultaneously.

```
public class BubbleSortTmp {
    public String[] Country = {"z", "h", "a"};
    public int[] City = {3, 2, 1};

    public void printCountry() {
        for (String s : Country) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printCity() {
        for (int s : City) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void sort() {
        for (int outer = Country.length - 1; outer > 0; outer--) {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++) {
                if (Country[inner].compareTo(Country[inner+1]) > 0) {
                    swapCountry(inner, inner+1);
                    swapCity(inner, inner+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void swapCountry(int first, int second) {
        String tmp = Country[first];
        Country[first] = Country[second];
        Country[second] = tmp;
    }

    private void swapCity(int first, int second) {
        int tmp = City[first];
        City[first] = City[second];
        City[second] = tmp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BubbleSortTmp bs = new BubbleSortTmp();

        System.out.println("Before: ");
        bs.printCountry();
        bs.printCity();

        bs.sort();

        System.out.println("After: ");
        bs.printCountry();
        bs.printCity();
    }
}
```